# How to determine vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am taking a linear algebra course, and we are currently learning about vector spaces and subspaces.

On the beginning of the chapter it is said that vector space must "comply" with all of the [ten rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) to actually be a vector space.

But throughout the rest of book for each example they only prove it for two axioms:

For example - The set {f | f:N->R } of all real-valued functions of one natural number variable is a vector space under the operations :
$$(f_1+f_2)(n) = f_1(n) + f_2(n)$$
and
$$(r\cdot f)(n) = r\cdot f(n).$$

and they do not test any further. What's with 8 remaining conditions for vector space?

So my question is, how to determine the vector space, with two axioms or all ten of them? And why do they prove it in book only for those two axioms?

$\cdot$ = multiplication

Comment: Vector space or subspace?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood something.  The "2 axioms" you mention are (in slightly garbled form) the definition of a linear transformation, not two axioms for a vector space.

Comment: If $V$ is a known vector space, and $W$ is a non-empty subset of $V$, then $W$ is a vector space if it satisfies the 2 axioms, since the others are automatic.

Comment: @hardmath functions on finite sets can be identified with vectors in a finite dimensional space.

Comment: For a subset of a vector space one only needs to check these closure axioms since any subset inherits the operations of the vector space.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think you are right, so subspaces are validated with 2 axioms and the rest of axioms is for spaces.

Comment: You have now added proper context. I guess what they do in the text, they define the two operations, and then *leave to you* the task of verifying that the axioms are indeed satisfied. Please do it, it's an instructive exercise.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you Andreas for your patience :) Nope it's just example so the reader can get a feeling for vector spaces, exercises are at the end of chapter. I don't see how can I do? this "exercise". It only shows that the set is closed under multiplication and addition.

Comment: @DusanJ. I'm pretty sure that the text says something like "It is not difficult to verify that the set of functions from the natural numbers to the real numbers becomes a real vector space under the following operations..."

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Nope :D Jim Hefferon, Linear Algebra page 85, it's free I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember a vector space is a set with two operations, addition and scalar multiplication...satisfying some axioms.

Here they have given you a set and told you how the two operations work. None of the axioms have been checked, that is up to you to do.

Answer (score 4):

From your notation, it seems that your *2 axioms* are the definitions of the operations that turn the set $V^A$ of all functions from a set $A$ to a vector space $V$ into a vector space.

Comment: This is what I thought about the question.

Comment: @B.S. OP has indeed edited the question in this direction.